# button press command works, but still says interaction failed; using discord-components

Tags: discord.py

The code does what is supposed to do, but after each button press it says "This interaction failed". Pressing the button edits the embed to change it to another. How would I get rid of that interaction failed message after pressing a button?

the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4dTd.png

code received from: https://github.com/elixss/YouTube/blob/main/source/buttons.py

Here is the code:

```
@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def help(ctx):

    # buttons
    one = Button(style=1, label="Commands", id="em1")
    two = Button(style=1, label="Depression", id="em2")
    three = Button(style=1, label="Moderator", id="em3")
    four = Button(style=1, label="Language", id="em4")

    # embeds
    em1 = Embed(title="Commands Plugin",color=0x5865F2)
    em2 = Embed(title="Depression Plugin", description="placeholder", color=0x5865F2)
    em3 = Embed(title="Moderator Plugin", description="placeholder", color=0x5865F2)
    em4 = Embed(title="Language Plugin", description="placeholder", color=0x5865F2)

    # main help embed
    help_embed = Embed(description="> **Help Module**\nPress on any button to view the commands for that selected plugin.",
                      color=discord.Color.random())

    # buttons to embeds
    buttons = {
        "em1": em1,
        "em2": em2,
        "em3": em3,
        "em4": em4
    }

    msg = await ctx.send(embed=help_embed,
                         components=[[one, two, three, four]])
    while True:
        event = await bot.wait_for("button_click", timeout=60.0)

        if event.channel is not ctx.channel:
            return

        if event.channel == ctx.channel:
            response = buttons.get(event.component.id)
            await msg.edit(embed=response)

            if response is None:
                await event.channel.send("error, try again.")
```

Comment: The embeds should be ```discord.Embed()``` and not just ```Embed()```

Comment: @ChaoticNebula No. He could've just done ``from discord import Embed`` instead of `import discord`. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: maybe.. he imported it directly? @ChaoticNebula

Comment: Yes, I used `from discord import Embed`

Comment: Which module are you using for the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elias said, you have to response to interactions, else it will show "This interaction failed", but not with a regular `ctx.send()` but with (in your case)

```
await event.respond(type=4, message="Responded!")
```

If you don't want to send a message as a response to a button click or selection in a select, you can just use `type=6` without message:

```
await event.respond(type=6)
```

For more types, see the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interaction-response-object-interaction-callback-type).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is to either remove all buttons after it's been pressed, or add a cooldown that will remove the buttons automatically after a certain time.

In your situation, it would look something like this:

```
msg = await ctx.send(embed=help_embed, components=[[one, two, three, four]])
try: 
   res = await client.wait_for("button_click", timeout = 60)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
   await msg.edit(components = []) #removes buttons from message
else:
   if res.author == message.author:
       #when button is clicked
       await msg.edit(components = [])
```

This also prevents being rate limited, so you don't have buttons constantly waiting for a response.

Comment: Yes, this is a way , but this is not the best way.